# Validating twitter bootstrap classes in an html code

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, lint

Does anybody know any solution to validate twitter bootstrap classes in an html code?

I mean checking code style rules for **row**s to make sure they are placed in a **container**, checking for **col**s to make sure they are in a **row**, ... and things like that!

I am not asking for "opinionated answers". **Opinionated answers** means only when you know **at least two different** solution to a question, not when you don't know anything about it.

I am asking for a tool like https://validator.w3.org but for validating classes in twitter bootstrap. Something like https://github.com/twbs/bootlint [bootlint doesn't support bootstrap v4!]

Comment: Oh get a hold of yourself and stop nagging me. You thought I gave you a downvote but I didn't - I DV just now. Nobody marked your question as spam, READ THE CLOSE NOTICE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bootlint](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) is the official Bootstrap linter. Judging by recent commits, this project is currently maintained.

It should be sufficient for your problem, for example [it will detect missplaced .row](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/wiki/E003).

Comment: thanks, but it seems Bootlint only supports Bootstrap v3. I asked to see if anybody knows a better solution.

Comment: Yep, you are right - I notice that they have error description for bootstrap v4, but looks like work only in progress and no ETA available.